# How to handle label click + checkbox click?

Tags: jquery

I run some validation on my form when a checkbox is clicked, which works as intended.

```
$('#ilikeicecream').click(function(){
     runValidation();
});
```

The checkbox also has a label element, so I need to check for that as well.  My first instinct was to do the following:

```
$('#ilikeicecream-label').click(function(){
     runValidation();
});
```

The problem is that the checkbox has not been checked at this point so validation does not work as intended.  How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/):

```
$('#ilikeicecream').change(function(){
     runValidation();
});
```

> For select boxes, **checkboxes**, and radio buttons, the event is fired
>   immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for
>   the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses
>   focus.

---

I've tested in jsFiddle with the following code. I'm unable to provide a link however as jsfiddle is currently down.

```
<label for="ilikeicecream">sdsd</label><input id="ilikeicecream" type="checkbox" />

$('#ilikeicecream').change(function(){
     alert("test");
});
```

---

If this is not working, perhaps you have not specified the `for` attribute in your `label` to match the `input`.

Comment: That was also something I tried without success.  Change doesn't seem to fire.

Comment: I've tested in jsfiddle and it works fine. Can you post your HTML?

Comment: @Beavis - If this is not working, perhaps you have not specified the for attribute in your label to match the input.

Answer (score 2):

this should work for you...

```
$('#ilikeicecream').change(function(){
     runValidation();
});

$('#ilikeicecream-label').click(function(){
     if($('#ilikeicecream').attr('checked')){
          $('#ilikeicecream').attr('checked', false);
     }
     else{
          $('#ilikeicecream').attr('checked', true);
     }
     runValidation();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the check-box with `<label>` tag. When you click label check-box will automatically change thus firing `change` event where you can invoke `runValidation()` function.

```
<label><input type="checkbox" value="1" id="blahblah" name="myname" /></label>
```

And keep the `.change` handler on check-box (you don't need separate one for its label)...

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#ilikeicecream-label').click(function(){
     // Swap the checked property value of the check box here
     runValidation();
})
```